# Get model only if relationship has data

Tags: laravel

I am working on a `Laravel` project and I have these two models `User` and `Post`:

```
user
-id
-name
-status

post
-id
-id_user
-name
```

What should I change from next line to have only `User` with at least one `Post` (I already created the one-to-many relationship in the models)?

```
$users = User::where('status', true)->get();
```

Comment: Since you've already created the relationship, it's as simple as `User::has('posts')->where('status', true)->get()`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Oh, i feel stupid now! Thanks man!

Comment: Don't feel stupid; if you don't know where to look in the docs, it can be a little confusing  Happy to help as always though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a one-to-many relationship, you can use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence and do this:

```php
User::has('posts')->whereTrue('status')->get()
```

If you need more power over `has`, you could use `whereHas`.